# Why do I have to return the second parameter as (struct sockaddr*)&ser_addr rather than &ser_addr?

Tags: linux, network-programming

I am doing a socket programming,and I am confused.
I find the System call bind(),its second parameter is const struct sockaddr* addr.
Apparently，it is a pointer parameter.

```
int bind(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr,socklen_t addrlen);
```

But I find that the example programm is like this

```
bind(lfd, (struct sockaddr*)&ser_addr, sizeof(ser_addr))
```

It pass a (struct sockaddr*)&ser_addr argument to the bind.
I wander know why.

Comment: I wonder why you wonder - in both cases it's the same, a pointer to `struct sockaddr`; and if `&ser_addr` is of an other type, isn't it understandable that the type has to be adjusted?

Comment: lol,I am a fishman ,thanks so much :-)